# How to explain attraction or repulsion of two current coil in terms of energy

Tags: electrostatics, magnetic-fields, potential-energy, quantum-electrodynamics, magnetostatics

We know  current (dc) carrying loop can be thought of a magnet .

And two current carrying loop (placed closely) will attract or repel each other depending on orientation of coil and direction of current and **this effect can be easily explained by biot savart law**

But **how to explain this phenomenon (attraction or repulsion) in terms of energy** like we generally do in electrostatics where minimisation of potential energy is key for attraction and repulsion.

Comment: Probably you can derive the force from the negative gradient of the total electromagnetic energy generated by the loops. This force will try to attract or repulse the current loops until the total energy is minimized.

Comment: @Jaime_mc2  how to define total energy? Let's say attraction takes place (and both coils having DC current due to current sources) and as coils come close, mutual inductance energy increases, so how actually total  energy(mentioned by you) is minimized in this case?

Comment: By total electromagnetic energy, I mean the energy stored in the fields themselves due to the configuration of the system. The two loops together will create a magnetic field (neglecting electric forces between moving charges) spread along all the space, and the energy stored in this field on a volume $V$ is $1/2 \int_V \mathbf{H}\cdot\mathbf{B}\, dV$. The total energy is calculated by taking the limit where $V$ covers the whole space. My guess is that the resulting force is the one which lowers the total energy of the system by trying to change its configuration (position of the loops).